# Web scraping: html structure visible with chrome developer tool, but not with htmlTreeParse (R)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, r, web-scraping

I use R to do web scraping, with following packages : XML, RCurl, httr, etc.

I have an issue when scraping this site:

```
url="http://www.elysee.fr/declarations/?search_index=2"
```

I try to do some text mining with the speeches of the French president. However I can not get read the html page as usually.

Usually, I first try to inspect the html page with Chrome developer tool.

```
page = htmlTreeParse((url),useInternal = TRUE,encoding="utf8")
```

For this page, with Chrome developer tool, I can see that I can get the href for all speeches with this `class:a[@class="main-link"]`. so I will usually do:

```
links = unlist(xpathApply(page, '//a[@class="main-link"]', xmlGetAttr,"href"))
```

However, there was not `a[@class="main-link"]` in the html code. And actually, when I download the html page with :

```
dput(getURL(url),"page.txt")
```

I can not find any (`class="main-link"`) in `page.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: selenium ! and with R, there is a package: rselenium.